# How to properly align menu items when window is resized?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build menu bar for my first website. On the window resolution of 1280x800 menu is seen properly. However, when scaling it down, Menu starts aligning incorrectly.

HTML:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'home/style.css' %}"/>

<div class="menu">
    <a href="/" class="logo"></a>
    <a href="/shop" class="shopbtn" style="text-decoration:none">Buy Cherry</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: lightgrey;
}


.menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: white;
    min-height: 10%;
    min-width: 150%;
}


.logo {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    right: 0%;
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/kMdEoP6.png');
    width: 250px;
    height: 55px;

    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.logo:hover {
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/7d2V63b.png');
    width: 249px;
    height: 55px;
}

.shopbtn {
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 12pt;
    right: 10%;
    left: 23%;
    top: 5%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: black;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    float: right;
}

.shopbtn:hover {
    color: darkred;
```

I have tried adding `margin-left` and `margin-right` with auto statement on all the elements, but the menu would mess up and still would go incorrectly when resized.

---

What is solution for keeping navigator proper when scaled? Is there any layout that could solve the problem? Can this be done without use of Javascript?

Comment: Add your full code, as over-here only buy cherry link is visible, Can't see your logo. Create a jsfiddle would be very helpful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `position fixed` from both logo and shopbtn and add `float left` as below,

```
.logo {
   float:left;
}
.shopbtn {
   background:#666666;
   float:left;  
   margin:20px;
}
```

Now adjust your padding and margin accordingly.

Comment: Thank's a lot! Since it is not in fixed position, would this still follow the window even when scrolled down?

Comment: Welcome @ShellRox :-), well it get's scrolled up,as position isn't fixed.

Comment: Is there any way so it can follow scroll? Both elements are in div layout which is fixed.

Comment: You have to put them in div and set that div position to fixed. By doing this it stays at top on windows.

Comment: Welcome @ShellRox :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can add `min-width` to the `<body>` tag and set your desired width size. It can help maintain your page size whenever you try to scale it down.

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  min-width: 800px;
}
```

Edit: Try changing your `.logo`'s `position` to `relative`.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't solve the problem, i could still scale the menu down and it would still mess up.

Comment: I didn't notice the `menu`. It will stay beside or wherever you put the `menu` when you scale down the window. Try changing the `position` to `relative`. Just play around on the values.

Comment: relative position made logo disappear at all, i've tried few values but the logo was nowhere/

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: white;
  min-height: 10%;
  min-width: 150%;
}
.logo {
  position: relative;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  background-image: url('images/logo.png');
  width: 250px;
  height: 55px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.logo:hover {
  background-image: url('images/logohover.png');
  width: 249px;
  height: 55px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'home/style.css' %}" />

<div class="menu">
  <a href="/" class="logo">Logo</a>
  <a href="/shop" class="shopbtn" style="text-decoration:none">Buy Cherry</a>
</div>
```

Update: Change the `.logo`'s position to `relative`. Maybe this is the one that you are looking for.

Comment: I can only see the logo label and little piece of background image to fit the text, I can't set the width/height of relative position manually.

Comment: What is your desired output? I put a "Logo" label to see if it displays.